# Is it possible to add a remote Linux printer to Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, printing, printer, lpr

My university has a Sharp MX-2614 industrial printer. To print on it, one can save the document as .pdf, SSH into the university Linux-based server and then use the [`lpr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol) command to print.

Would it be possible to add the printer directly to my Windows laptop to make it easier to print? The printer does not seem to be directly accessible via IP for students; I only know of access via the SSH server.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could simplify the process by doing something like `cat yourfile.pdf | ssh user@yourubuntumachine lpr`, credit: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26433/how-to-print-over-ssh

Comment: @adampski 1° I’m using Windows, as indicated in the question. 2° Piping cat is perverse.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the printer as an lpr printer on Windows. In the following I'm assuming Win7, but other versions of Windows are similar.

Go to Devices & Printers and click on "Add a printer". Make sure you add a "local" printer. When asked for the port, create a new Standard TCP/IP port with the linux host's IP address. If Windows cannot find it, create a Custom port and set it to LPR, with the linux printer name as the queue name. If Windows does find the host, still make sure it is set to LPR, if necessary by going to Printer Properties > Ports > Configure Port. Finish the installation by telling Windows the printer model. Make sure you have driver files handy.

You could also install the printer as a local printer connected to LPT1 or FILE. Then go to the Ports tab and create the required TCP/IP port.

Comment: And where am i supposed to enter my SSH login and password?

Comment: If this printer is shared on the linux box, then lpr is all you need.

Comment: How is windows supposed to know how to connect to the linux server?

Comment: It does not need to login to the server, it only needs to access the printer. It does that in the same way that linux uses a printer on another linux system: by connecting to the printer via lpr. In fact, if the printer is network connected, you can connect to the printer itself, again via lpr. Every network printer supports that.

Comment: Yes, but i’m not able to access it without entering my linux password.